# Create event source as part Visual Studio Setup Project installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, event-viewer

Is there a way to create an event source for Windows Event Viewer with a Visual Studio Setup Project so that it is created when the solution is installed on the client machine?

Comment: What are you using to create the installer? [This extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)?

Comment: Yes, that extension